# Entity Framework 4 Code Only Error "Multiple objects sets per type are not supported"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have two "Code Only" POCO's using EF4 and the latest CTP, running against an existing, legacy database. Running a LINQ query against PocoA worked until I added the property below to that object, I was trying to add a relationship.

```
public virtual PocoB pocoB { get; set; }
```

Once I did that, I started getting the following error:

`Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'PocoA_DbSet' and 'PocoB_DbSet' can both contain instances of type 'PocoA'.`

So I next thought my problem was because I had not defined the relationship, and this legacy database was using a 'fk/pk' prefix instead of an 'Id' suffix on the primary and foreign keys.  So I added the following data annotation to the virtual method specified above, with no change in behavior:

```
[RelatedTo(Property="PocoB", ForeignKey="fkPocoB")]
```

I'm really at a loss for what needs to be changed to make this work.

Comment: Can you provide your `PocoA` and `PocoB` classes. Also, any related mapping classes.

Comment: Found the problem.  It was a typo.  My DbSet class for PocoB was declared as `DbSet<PocoA>`.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it... That'll take this question off the unanswered list :)

Comment: agreed, nothing more annoying than getting this far and finding the issue has been resolved. :(

Answer (score 47):

This error occurs if your DbContext class exposes multiple DbSet<T> properties where T occurs more than once. Basically it can't figure out which DbSet an instance of type T belongs to.

In code, the error probably looked like this:

```
public class MyContex : DbContext {
    public DbSet<PocoA> PocoA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PocoA> PocoB { get; set; } ...
```

where that final line should have been DbSet<PocoB> instead of DbSet<PocoA>

**TL;DR** - you copy-pasted a property and **forgot to change the type parameter** in the DbSet.

Comment: Thank you for following up.  Saved me a headache :)

Comment: Just fell victim to the same thing due to copy+paste. This saved me some time.

Comment: Same problem. I did the same thing.. copy-paste!